# Linq to sql.  Many to many table join

Tags: linq-to-sql, many-to-many

I have been building a Motion Picture application to manage actors or "Talents".   I have a TALENT table and a LANGUAGES table.   I also have a TALENTLANGUAGES table that shows the many to many relationship between the two.

Here is the SQL i can write to show the different languages a given talent speaks.

```
Select t.TalentID, t.FirstName, tl.LanguageID, l.Name from Talent t
inner join TalentLanguage tl on tl.TalentID = t.TalentID
inner join Language l on l.LanguageID = tl.LanguageID
where t.TalentID = 10000;
```

Im in my C# application I'm using Linq to sql classes.  How might I do the above code with linq to sql.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remus, I think I'm gonna answer this myself because it's such a clean solution.  Check this out...

```
var languages = from tl in talentDB.TalentLanguages
                where tl.TalentID == id
                select new { lang = tl.Language.Name, tal_id = tl.TalentID };  // could get more values if needed..

foreach (var l in languages)
{
    string language = l.lang;
    string talentID = l.tal_id; 
    // etc...
}
```

This is pretty cool!  Linq did the join for me!!

Comment: The 'var' type basically creates a soft-typed, temporary container.  Glad this worked out for you.

Comment: Yeah this is what I need in my case, a temporary container.  Both solutions should work.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it:

Start by creating a "results" object, something that will hold the information that you need in one object.  Let's call it "TalentLanguagesContainer"

```
public class TalentLanguagesContainer
{
    public int TalentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
    public string LanguageName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, create a Select statement that will map your needs appropriately:

```
public IQueryable < TalentLanguagesContainer > GetTalentLanguages()
{           
       MyDataContext _dataContext = new MyDataContext();

       return _dataContext.TalentLanguages
                  .Where(t => t.TalentID == 10000)
                  .Select(tl => new TalentLanguagesContainer() {
                             TalentID = tl.TalentID,
                             FirstName = tl.Talent.FirstName,
                             LanguageID = tl.LanguageID,
                             LanguageName = tl.Language.Name });
}
```

Also, you may want to consider writing stored procedures for more complex scripts such as this one - you may find an SQL script to perform faster too.

Comment: Remus, Thanks for the response.  Looks good, I think there's a bug on your Where clause.   Is there a way to do this without creating a container.  I'm really new to linq.

Comment: I haven't tested this code - there might be bugs, the approach is what you should take from it though.  As for doing it without creating a container, what are you thinking of having returned?

Comment: oops - updated 'where' statement to use "==", instead of "=", that will probably fix the bug you were talking about.

Comment: No, I don't think you can do a where like that.  I'm not getting any intelisense anyways..